# Covert JSON object keys into sentence case (Add space & capitalize each word) Angular 12

Tags: json, angular, camelcasing, angular12, sentencecase

I've already gone through some of the related questions & answers, but unfortunately those didn't solve my issue.

In my situation, I'm converting a **string into JSON**. In the front-end, I have got the values & headers of the converted JSON by using

`this.values = JSON.parse(element["record"].replace(/\\/g, ""))`

&

`this.headers = Object.keys(this.record)`

I want to show the headers inside a table as table-header. So, I need sentence case. For example-

Header value- thisIsMyHeader

What I want- This Is My Header

Can anyone please tell a way to add space between each word of the camel case text & make each word's first letter capital in **Angular 12** that will actually work without giving me error?

**NOTE**:- I wouldn't like to use 'lodash'

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.headers = [ 'testThisOne']
let newHeaders = []
this.headers.forEach( (header : string) => {
    let newHeader = [];
    let chars = Array.from(header);
    chars.forEach((char : string => {
        if (char.toUpperCase() && char != char.toLowerCase()){
            newHeader.push( ' ');
            newHeader.push( char);
        
        } else {
            newHeader.push(char);
        }
        newHeader[0] = newHeader[0].toUpperCase();
        
    })
    newHeaders.push(newHeader.join(''));
});
this.headers = newHeaders;
console.log(this.headers);
```